# Cypher finding user(s) with the highest count of products

Tags: neo4j, count, cypher

I have set of nodes: `(u:User)-[:OWN]->(p:Product)`

I need to identify the user(s) who owns the most products.

I can get close by using:

```
MATCH (u:User)-[r]->(p:Product)
RETURN u.value as user, count(p.value) as Pcount
order by Pcount desc
limit 3

user    cntProduct
Sammy   16
Bob     16
jo      12
```

But I'd like to return only "Sammy" and "Bob". So limit is not a good option as I don't know how many users will qualify.

Any ideas how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
MATCH (u:User)-[:OWN]->(p:Product)
WITH u, COUNT(p.value) as count // calc de count for every user
WITH MAX(count) as max // save the 'max' value from 'count' (16, in your case)
MATCH (u:User)-[:OWN]->(p:Product)
WITH u, COUNT(p.value) as count, max
WHERE count = max // pass by WITH only when 'count' is equals 16
RETURN u.value as user, count
```

Tested here with a little data set and worked fine.

Comment: Thanks Bruno; this works great! very clever.  (In the meantime I came up with and idea of creating set of nodes per user that store the user and the count of product they own.                                                                         
    MATCH (u:User)-[:OWN]->(p:Product)
    with u.value as user, count(p.value) as cnt_prod
    MERGE (tot:total{u:user, tot:cnt_prod});
and then

    match (t:total)
    return t.cnt_prod as Max, collect(t.user) as users
    order by Max desc
    limit 1;    this works but not very nice solution